# how can i loop through the array inside of an object. and render it in the react component

Tags: reactjs, loops, javascript-objects

i wanted to loop through the array inside on an object and pull the data to render in the react component. but i don't know how to use map to the array inside on the object. i tried many way's but it's not working

```js
const [emailData, setEmailData] = useState("");

res?.data.emails.map((email) =>  
    setEmailData(
        <Table.Row>
            <Table.Cell>{email.emailed_to}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{email.notes}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{email.created_at}</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
    );
);

return ({ emailData });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Object functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) for that which wrap your object.

```
const object1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

There are 3 versions of it:

- Keys: `Object.keys(object1)` returns an array of all keys => `[a,b,c]`
- Values: `Object.values(object1)` returns an array of all values => `[1,2,3]`
- Entries: `Object.entries(object1)` returns an array of all entires as an array of arrays=> `[[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]]`

The last one could be used like this

```
Object.entries(object1).map(([key, value]) => ....)
```

Comment: @Shuvo Perfect, if this helped you, could you mark it as accepted so other might find it as well?